# Как проскролить страницу к елементу без jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Как сделать на чистом JavaScript?

```
$(".icon").on("click", function() {

$("html, body").animate({

scrollTop : $(".content").offset().top

}, 800);

});
```

Comment: С помощью `window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);` и `addEventListener();` позже напишу в ответе как, сейчас занят...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var icon = document.querySelector('.icon'),
            content = document.querySelector('.content');
        icon.onclick = function() {
            scrollTo(800, content.offsetTop);
        }

        function scrollTo(duration, position) {
            var beginPosition = 0,
                step = duration/position,
                scrollInterval = setInterval(function() {
                    if (beginPosition<= position){
                        window.scroll(0, beginPosition);
                        beginPosition += 1;
                    } else clearInterval(scrollInterval);
                }, step);
        }
```

При клике на элемент с классом `icon` вызываем функцию `scrollTo()`, в которую передаем продолжительность прокрутки к элементу (800) и позицию к которой нужно проскроллить.
Чтобы сделать прокрутку плавной, используем `setInterval()`, в который передаем `step - 800` на позицию блока с классом `content`.